# How can I remove specific group of marker from map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I have added different groups of my manually created markers to the map. now I want remove the specific group of markers from the map. I've tried using .remove(); and clear() methods, didn't worked. here is my code.

```
 HashMap<Integer,Marker> aa = new HashMap<>();

 void addAtmkMarker(LatLng latLng, String title, boolean status) {
    Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: Clearing Previous location");
    if (mMap != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: Moving Camera to current location");
      

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title)
                .icon(status ? BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_green) : BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_red));
        mAtm = mMap.addMarker(options);
        i++;
        aa.put(i,mAtm); //created hashmap to store status of multiple markers. 



    }
}



 atm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked()){
                    addAtmkMarker(new LatLng(latLng.latitude + Math.random() * (0 - 0.005), latLng.longitude + Math.random() * (0 - 0.005)), "SBI", true);
                    addAtmkMarker(new LatLng(latLng.latitude + Math.random() * (0.005 - 0), latLng.longitude + Math.random() * (0 - 0.005)), "BOI", true);
                    addAtmkMarker(new LatLng(latLng.latitude + Math.random() * (0.005 - 0), latLng.longitude + Math.random() * (0 - 0.005)), "SBI", false);
                    addAtmkMarker(new LatLng(latLng.latitude + Math.random() * (0.005 - 0), latLng.longitude + Math.random() * (0 - 0.005)), "SBI", true);

                }
                else{
                    for(int j=0;j<=4;j++) //logic implemented for removing marker but didn't worked.
                    {
                        aa.remove(j);
                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove marker with using markerName.
Firstly get name then remove it.

```
aa.get(j).remove()
```

Comment: Debug your code and make sure you are getting your marker title before remove operation. Because you need marker name for removing it.